# Serenity BDD fun features by groups

Tags: java, cucumber, automated-tests, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I use Serenity BDD + Cucumber to perform my test, in fact that I have too many tests I need to run hem separately sometimes. Is it possible to execute Serenity BDD features by groups? Like in jUnit `@Group(MyTestGroup.class)`?

I can not find any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tagging for that purpose. Information about that feature can be found in Serenity BDD [official documentation](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_annotating_scenarios_with_tags).

Just a short excerpt, tags are added to jUnit tests using `WithTag` annotation. The following will add a tag of type `feature` (this is a default Serenity type) with name `Reporting`:

```
@WithTag(type="feature", name="Reporting")
```

Then you can run tests with this tag with jUnit like this:

```
mvn clean verify -Dtags="feature:Reporting"
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation [Running Serenity BDD tests with Tags](https://johnfergusonsmart.com/running-serenity-bdd-tests-with-tags/).

You can use -Dcucumber.options=" --tags '@Reporting'"